# Panel con otro Panel mas grande en su interior

Tags: c#, vb.net, windows-forms

Estoy creando un control de usuario en `windows forms`, dicho control de usuario tiene dos zonas, la zona superior donde hay un texto descriptivo y un botón de adelante y otro para ir hacia atrás.

En la zona inferior hay otro panel que ocupa todo el espacio disponible.
Dentro del panel inferior quiero meter otro panel ( o el control que mejor se ajuste a mis necesidades), que sera significativamente mayor que el espacio del que dispone ahora, así que lo que necesito es que ese panel se pueda mover de arriba hacia abajo, es decir que se le pueda agregar una barra de control para tal propósito.

La verdad es que el problema es que no se que controles son los mejores para esta operativa y como desarrollarlo, si alguien me puede poner algún ejemplo o algunas lineas maestras le estaría muy agradecido.
Como veis no pongo codigo porque relamente mi problema es anterior al propio desarrollo.

Si alguien considera que la pregunta no es correcta por no tener código la retiro sin ningún problema.

El programa esta desarrollado en `VB` para el `Framework 2.0`.
No me importa que me deis una solucion en `C#`, ya que es un tema conceptual, ya lo traduciré yo después,
Gracias.

Edito. Añado imagenes

[image: Pantalla principal dividida en dos ares]

La imagen superior se corresponde con la pantalla principal donde se en la parte derecha se introducirá el control de usuario cuya imagen esta debajo de estas lineas.

[image: Simulación del control de usuario que se quiere introducir en la parte derecha de la pantalla principal]

Sobre estas lineas el control de usuario que quiero introducir en la pantalla principal.
Como se ve, es bastante mas largo que el espacio que tiene asignado en la pantalla principal, asi que lo ideal seria que se pudiese haber un scroll bar a la derecha o algo similar.
Gracias.

Comment: Podes agregar una imagen de tu formulario actual y como queres que quede?

Comment: @AlejandroRicotti He añadido las imagenes, gracias.

Comment: Que control has metido dentro del segundo panel? Has probado a poner la propiedad `AutoScroll` del panel a true?

Comment: Hola @Pikoh, se trata de un user control que se divide en la parte de arriba por un panel, y en la parte de abajo otro panel que crece hasta ocupar todo el espacio, lo otro son listas para simular lo que habra en el  futuro. si es mejor hacerlo con otro tipo de control no tengo ningun problema en cambiarlo, gracias.

Comment: Gracias @Pikoh parece que jugando con el autoscroll podre lograrlo. un saludo.

Comment: De nada. Me alegro que te sirva :)